# Spring Autowire XML: value is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, enumeration

I am trying to run a code for Spring Auto wiring. I am using "autodetect" as autowire attribute value for bean configuration. I am getting below error.

```
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [com/example/autowire/autodetect/application-context.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 12 in XML document from class path resource [com/example/autowire/autodetect/application-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-enumeration-valid: Value 'autodetect' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[default, no, byName, byType, constructor]'. It must be a value from the enumeration. at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:212)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:126)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:92)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
at com.example.autowire.autodetect.TestAutowire.main(TestAutowire.java:9)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-enumeration-valid: Value 'autodetect' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[default, no, byName, byType, constructor]'. It must be a value from the enumeration.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:423)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3188)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processOneAttribute(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2783)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processAttributes(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2720)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2072)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:711)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:400)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2756)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:647)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:232)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
... 14 more
```

Here is the Code:**application-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />

<bean id="employee" class="com.example.autowire.autodetect.EmployeeBean" autowire="autodetect">
    <property name="fullName" value="Mandar"/> 
</bean>

<bean id="department" class="com.example.autowire.autodetect.DepartmentBean" >
    <property name="name" value="IT" />
</bean>
```

**DepartmentBean.java**

```
package com.example.autowire.autodetect;

public class DepartmentBean{
   private String name;

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }
}
```

**EmployeeBean.java**

```
package com.example.autowire.autodetect;

public class EmployeeBean
{
   private String fullName;

   private DepartmentBean departmentBean;

   public DepartmentBean getDepartmentBean() {
       return departmentBean;
   }

   public void setDepartmentBean(DepartmentBean departmentBean) {
       this.departmentBean = departmentBean;
   }

   public String getFullName() {
       return fullName;
   }

   public void setFullName(String fullName) {
       this.fullName = fullName;
   }
}
```

**TestAutowire.java**

```
package com.example.autowire.autodetect;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class TestAutowire {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = 
              new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"com/example/autowire/autodetect/application-context.xml"});

            EmployeeBean employee = (EmployeeBean)context.getBean("employee");
            System.out.println(employee.getFullName());
            System.out.println(employee.getDepartmentBean().getName());
    }
}
```

Please suggest solution on this.

Comment: `'[default, no, byName, byType, constructor]'. It must be a value from the enumeration.` You have `autodetect`. Perhaps try doing what the message says, or simply dropping that attribute entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `autodetect` option for `autowire` attribute has been deprecated as of `Spring 3.0`. Hence, this option is not available `Spring 3.0` onwards.

If you see [2.5.6 XSD](http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd), the value autodetect is there, but its not available in [3.0 XSD](http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd).

Your options:

1. Try using some other option for `autowire` attribute.
2. Downgrade your spring version to `2.x`.

Comment: Thank you. Will use any other value like 'default', as per spring 3.0.